# Joomla! Template Designer "fight" Component Developer

Tags: templates, components, joomla2.5, relationship

Assume that i am working in a Joomla 2.5 team. I am a "good" template designer and other are "bad" component developers, just kidding.

Some day, they completed a perfect "PC Management" component. 
Yes, i was really happy when with this component structure, i could paint a good looking layout into Photoshop and convert to HTML and CSS successfully! Boss was satisfied. Website worked perfect.

But yesterday, component developers group had got some new idea. They added some new fields with a lot of new div tags, they also changed class some div tags. My template was broken. I know to how to override layout with html/component_name folder. But if there are any additional items to component, i again copy component view folders to my html folder, correct?

My question: Is there any idea about "perfect" relationship between template and component in Joomla? I mean, in my case, if component structure changes, must i change my template too? Do my team have to discuss some any changes? Do i have got any else choices to work isolatedly.

Sorry because of my bad English! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First, once you have added a template override to `templates/YOUR TEMPLATE/html/component_name` you should not have to do anything when a component is updated. The override folder is not touched by components by design. The only issue you might have is if they dramatically change how the component works and the override is no longer compatible.

As for the interaction between component devs and templates, there is a lot a component dev SHOULD do to keep the impact on a template low. First, they should standardize the CSS ids and classes they use. Next, they should avoid inserting any inline CSS or hard coding anything that should be part of the template. Any markup in the components core views should follow best practices and be W3C valid code. It should go without saying that the component should also be proper Joomla MVC so overrides work as intended. A component done well should drop in to any template without breaking anything.

Comment: Thank for your reply! As you say "A component done well should drop in to any template without breaking anything.". Does it mean, component developers should make layout for their component themselves? I (a template designer) will not care about their component?

Comment: Component developers will have to make some sort of layout, but it should be created with overall template design in mind. That means not hard coding anything in to the template files or using absolute pixel sizes if you can avoid it. Generally you will want your component to be fluid so it fits within the template regardless of the width being used for the component area.

As a template designer it would be impossible to account for every component out there. You may want to create a set of overrides for a particular component if it is popular - K2, Virtuemart, etc, but otherwise ignore them.